# Issue migrating a checkbox-type meta field to the block editor

Tags: javascript, hooks, post-meta, block-editor, save-post

I'm trying to add Gutenberg support to a plugin that registers a custom post type with a checkbox-type meta field called `_meta_restrict`, while maintaining back-compatibility with the classic editor at the same time. I've made some progress but I'm stuck now and need a bit of help.

This is the relevant code I'm using to register and save the meta field value in the classic editor:

```
function register_meta_field() {
    register_post_meta( 'custom_post_type', '_meta_restrict', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
        }
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_meta_field' );

function add_custom_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'custom-meta-box',
        'Options',
        'custom_meta_box_callback',
        'custom_post_type',
        'side',
        'low',
        array(
            '__block_editor_compatible_meta_box' => false,
            '__back_compat_meta_box' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_boxes' );

function save_custom_post_type( $post_id ) {
    // verify nonce
    if ( isset( $_POST['metabox_nonce'] ) && !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['metabox_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // is autosave?
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) ) {
        if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } elseif ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    }

    // save meta field
    $meta_restrict = isset( $_POST['meta_restrict'] ) ? $_POST['meta_restrict'] : '';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_meta_restrict', $meta_restrict );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_post_type' );
```

In the block editor, I added a `ToggleControl` to the `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` in order to manage my `_meta_restrict` meta field. This is the code I came up with:

```
let RestrictControl = ({ restrict, onUpdateRestrict }) => (
    <ToggleControl
        label={ 'Restrict viewing?' }
        help={ restrict ? 'Viewing is restricted.' : 'Viewing is not restricted.' }
        checked={ restrict }
        onChange={ restrict => onUpdateRestrict( restrict ) }
    />
);

RestrictControl = compose( [
    withSelect( ( select ) => {
        return {
            restrict: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )['_meta_restrict']
        };
    } ),
    withDispatch( ( dispatch ) => {
        return {
            onUpdateRestrict: ( value ) => {
                dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost({ meta: { _meta_restrict: value } })
            }
        }
    } ),
] )( RestrictControl );
```

This code works perfectly. The issue is that after the meta field value is saved via `rest_insert_{$this->post_type}`, the classic editor `save_post` action is also fired, so the meta field is overwritten with an empty value because `$_POST['meta_restrict']` is not available in the block editor. If I comment my `save_custom_post_type` function, the value is successfully saved in the block editor, but I need to provide backwards compatibility with the classic editor.

How am I supposed to do this? Why is the `save_post` action fired even though `__block_editor_compatible_meta_box` is set to false and `__back_compat_meta_box` is set to true? Can I disable it from running when working in the block editor?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. I had to change the nonce check in `save_custom_post_type()` to:

```
if ( !isset( $_POST['metabox_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['metabox_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
    return $post_id;
}
```